# Genemotion shows booting

Tags: genymotion

I have installed Genemotion 3.3.1 (https://dl.genymotion.com/releases/genymotion-3.3.1/genymotion-3.3.1-vbox.exe) on my windows 10 Pro . This file bundles both genymotion and virtualbox. Genymotion doesnt boot up and gets stuck on the same page. See attached.

1.Tried rebooting the machine after installing Genymotion(3.3.1) and Virtualbox(6.1.36).
2.Ensured that Hyper-V and its components are unchecked in Control panel -> Windows components.

I dont have any graphics card on my machine. Will this be a problem?

Are there any logs which would provide more insight ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont have any graphics card on my machine. Will this be a problem?

Yes: Genymotion needs OpenGL to render the device display, so a GPU is mandatory. Also do not try to run it on a server: it won't work and it is against [the conditions of use](https://www.genymotion.com/legal-terms-and-conditions/).

Comment: Thanks Julien for helping me with the details.